# Como trazer o resultado de uma consulta que o valor de uma coluna não contenha em outra coluna

Tags: sql, query

Vejam a situação, tenho uma tabela que tem a coluna NUMETAPAPAI e NUMETAPA o que preciso é trazer no resultado da consulta somente os dados que a NUMETAPA não contenha valores iguais a NUMETAPAPAI mesmo que em outra linha como é o caso deste print.

```sql
SELECT  E.NUFAP,
        E.NUMETAPAPAI PAI,
        E.NUMETAPA,
        E.DESCRICAO,
        E.CONCLUIDA
FROM TCSFAP F
FULL OUTER JOIN TGFPAR P ON F.CODPARC = P.CODPARC
FULL OUTER JOIN TCSFET E ON E.NUFAP = F.NUFAP 
WHERE E.NUFAP = '4' 
AND E.CONCLUIDA = 'N' 
AND E.NUMETAPAPAI <> '99999'
AND E.NUMETAPA <> E.NUMETAPAPAI
ORDER BY E.NUMETAPAPAI, E.NUMETAPA
```

[CONSULTA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdPkz.jpg)

Comment: Tente com NOT EXISTS https://www.techstrikers.com/MySQL/mysql-not-exists-operator.php

Answer (score -3):

Olá, até onde tenho conhecimento você poderia usar dois métodos do próprio SQL para chegar no seu objetivo:

1. Usar o método `DISTINCT` para procurar por valores distintos, mas não consegui fazer este funcionar relacionado com multiplas colunas igual você pediu.
2. Usar o método `GROUP BY` para agrupar os resultados que tenham registros repetidos em tabelas que diferem.

Não consegui aplicar em seu código pois o nome das tabelas estão confusos para eu conseguir replicar em minha máquina. Caso queira deixarei os links de referencia de ambos os comandos e uma discussão no StackOverflow em inglês que achei semelhante.

[SQL Group By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[SQL DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

[Discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: O que preciso é de uma forma de não trazer nenhum resultado na coluna NUMETAPA que contenha o mesmo valor na NUMETAPAPAI